# WordPress NOT redirecting from http to https SSL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, https

I have my WordPress Address (URL) and my Site Address in the WordPress settings as my url: `https://example.com/blog` but when I type in `http://example.com/blog`, it doesn't redirect it to the SSL version, even though I have the site address as https.

I disabled all the plugins and switched to the default theme but this still occurs. Any reasons as to why this is happening or solutions?

Comment: once you change the urls you still have to add a redirect: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache?

Comment: what do you mean change the URLs?

Answer (score 1):

You still have to redirect 'http' to 'https'.

You have several options, here are a couple:

**Option 1**

In your .htaccess file you can add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Just be sure to change www.example.com to whatever your domain should be (you don't need the www. if you don't want it.)

**Option 2**

Change your DNS to CloudFlare (free) and change the settings according to this:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-

However, if you want to use www. I recommend using two page rules so that you can redirect http to https and add www. in a single redirect. Doing both in a single redirect can be better for SEO. For both page rules, select the setting called "Forwarding URL" and "301" and make the rules as follows:

```
http://*example.com/*
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/$2
```

**and**

```
https://*example.com/*
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/$2
```

This is assuming that you are not using subdomains. If you are, let me know and I can update the answer with rules that will accommodate subdomains.

Comment: Using cloudflare's "page rules" -> Always use https solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to update .htaccess file after installing SSL. So you should add the following code to your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

After that, for cross-checking regarding your website all pages are properly redirected to https or not, follow steps & use tools mentioned in this [resource](https://www.clickssl.net/blog/how-to-fix-mixed-content-warning-other-ssl-settings-in-wordpress).